App not installed as a package appears to be invalid on Android 13
I am using Unity 2021.3.6f1
I have built the application with different target API levels (level 27, level 30, level 34), minimum API 22, and all these versions work on my Android 9 and Android 7.
However, when I share the file via Google Drive with a friend, he gets an error 'App not installed as a package appears to be invalid'.
He is using Android 13, and none of the builds worked for him. He said he deleted all previous APKs and the app itself, but it didn't help install the new version.
Also, in all the builds mentioned above, I used a new Project Keystore because I lost the old one. I can provide additional screenshots from Unity if needed. Thank you!
(On the screenshot, the error is translated from another language, so the wording may vary)

Upd:
Okay, I've created a new project and built it using API 34. Everything worked fine, and I've set the remaining settings the same as in the original project. Now I have no idea what could be causing the error.

You need a test device for better understanding what is going wrong. Have you at least tried to set-up an emulator running Android 13 and install you app there using adb install?

No, I haven't heard about that, thanks for the tip, I'll try it now

Updating Unity to 2022.3.21f1 solved the problem
